# Adding a classy or ID to the prestashop module

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I start the adventure with prestashop and I would like to have a problem. I have no idea how to add a classe or ID to the module.

My code is:

```
    <h3>Mini Top Menu</h3>
  <ul>
          <li>
        <a id="link-cms-page-1-3" class="cms-page-link" href=""link1 title="link1">
        </a>
      </li>
          <li>
        <a id="link-cms-page-4-3" class="cms-page-link" href="link1" title="link1">
        </a>
      </li>
          <li>
        <a id="link-cms-page-5-3" class="cms-page-link" href="link1" title="link1">
        </a>
      </li>
          <li>
        <a id="link-product-page-prices-drop-3" class="cms-page-link" href="link1" title="link1">
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
```

I would like to add this `<ul>` ID and get rid of the `<h3>` tag

I will add that I use Link Widget.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right:

You have to search for (menu) module on your theme folder to find .tpl files:

"themes/yourTheme/modules/TargetModule/*.tpl"

if this path not exist then you have to search on "modules/TargetModule/templates/...." to find your file.

Tip: don't forget to clear both PrestaShop and browser cache, after any change on tpls